# Flask, How to response a string to html?

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to write code to process the user posted data, and return a string type value and show it the page, here is my demo code

```
def model(...):
    ...
    strs = process(...)
    return render_template('page.html' ...)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: as in AJAX? If so, just send back a json structure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to pass `strs` inside the template `page.html`? You should take a look at the [official tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/) of flask to get a grasp of the basics.

```
def model(...):
    ...
    strs = process(...)
    return render_template('page.html', string_variable=strs)
```

The template `page.html` can then reference `strs` as `string_variable`:

```
<p>This is the processed string: {{ string_variable }} </p>
```